# Why am I getting RuntimeError: Session collision on '...'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, memcached

I've been getting quite a lot of session collision exceptions. Usually at least one per day, but sometimes I deploy and get 2-3 in a row and then nothing.

The app runs on Rails 3.2.2 and unicorn, and sessions are stored in memcached.

The exceptions happen in different places in different controllers and I'm not really able to find anything they have in common. What could be causing this?

Comment: I've never used memcached, but that's the first place I'd look... good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how ruby/rails handles session data using memcached but normally the work is as follows:

```
new session    -> using command ADD
update session -> using GET with token and than the command CAS (check and set)
```

If there is a hash collision the command ADD fails because the session already exists.
Another possible issue is if another process updated the same session between GET and CAS.